# sql assign a category id when using order by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I'm new to SQL.

When I order by SomeData on my table I get:

```
ID      SomeData
6       ABC
3       ABC
12      FG
1       FH
2       GI
4       JU
8       K3
5       K3
11      P7
```

great. but what i really want on output is

```
ID      Category
6       1
3       1
12      2
1       3
2       4
4       5
8       6
5       6
11      7
```

That is every time SomeData changes on the sort I want to increment Category by one

I can't see how to do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try using window functions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx

Comment: How you do this will very likely depend on the database you are using (Oracle? MySQL? MS-SQL? ...). So what are you using?

Comment: If you are on SQL-Server, you could use something like `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SomeData)` to get this increasing category id.

Answer (score 3):

If you are on SQL-Server, you can use the `DENSE_RANK()` ranking function in combination with `OVER`:

```
SELECT ID
     , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SomeData)
       AS Category
FROM myTable
ORDER BY SomeData
```

See: [**SQL-Server: Ranking Functions**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SomeData ASC) AS Category, otherfield1..
```

Comment: ROW_NUMBER() seems to just assign 1,2,...7 to each row

Comment: seems to me that this is somewhat like subtotalling on a report when the month changes during a sort.